# X-Axis tick spacing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to format my x-Axis.

I have Values for 585,590,595,605. I already eliminated the tick for 600 but now I have a huge gap there. What's the solution to get a clean look?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Tabelle = pd.read_excel(
    "C:\\Users\\alexk\\Dropbox\\WW\\WW Master\\1. Semester\\WW2\\WW2 Kernfachpraktikum\\KFP2\\Ergebnisse.xlsx",
    "Auswertung Zugversuche T-d")

T = Tabelle["T./°C"]

y = Tabelle["MW. Rp0,2"]
y2 = Tabelle["MW. Rm"]
y3 = Tabelle["MW. e"]

z1 = Tabelle["StabW. Rp0,2"]
z2 = Tabelle["StabW. Rm"]
z3 = Tabelle["StabW. Rm"]

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)

ax1.bar(T, y, label=("Rp0,2")), ax1.bar(T, y2, label=("Rm"))
ax1.set_title("Titel")
ax1.set_xlabel("Gießtemperatur / °C")
ax1.set_ylabel("Rp0,2 und Rm / MPa")
ax1.set_ylim(0, 250)

ax1.set_xticks(T)
# Values in T:585,590,595,605

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

That's how it looks at the moment:

[image]

Comment: How would you like it to look?

Comment: I just started this figure. I just want the gap between 595 and 605 to disappear. I'll do the rest of the formattion myself. The bars should be evenly spread along the axis.

Comment: You can probably plot strings, `ax1.bar(T.astype(str), y, label=("Rp0,2"))` (in which case you need to remove `ax1.set_xticks(T)`)

Comment: Damn, thanks ImportanceOfBeingErnest. That did it! Cheers!

Comment: damn, ist there a way to move strings on the xaxis like ax1.bar(x +/-0,2 ,y)? I added a third set of y-data on a secondary axis and i cant work with align"edge" and width +/-0,5...

Comment: No, you cannot add strings to numbers. So in that case it would probably make sense to plot against the list index, then set the tick positions to the index and the ticklabels to the elements of `T`.