# x-xticks for discontinuous data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have discontinuous data for my x-Values T=(585,590,595,605). I need them to be spread evenly on the x-axis.

I can't use "T.astype(str)", because i need to add/substract a little bit because i have three bars for each value.

Here's what it looks like now:
[Click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKOuu.png)

Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Read exel file
Tabelle = pd.read_excel("path.xlsx", nrows=4)

# T = temperature for (x-axis):
T = Tabelle["T./°C"]
xpos = np.array(T, dtype=int)

# for Rp/Rm/e over T:
y = Tabelle["MW. Rm"]
y1 = Tabelle["MW. Rp0,2"]
y2 = Tabelle["MW. e"]

# barwidth
w = 0.33

# figures in grid:
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

# graph in 0,0:
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid(shape=(1, 2), loc=(0, 0))

# graphs in (0,0):
ax1.bar(xpos - 0.33, y, label="Rm", color="firebrick", width=-0.5, align="edge")
ax1.bar(xpos, y1, label="Rp0,2", color="c", width=0.5, align="center")
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.bar(xpos + 0.33, y2, label="ε-Bruch", color="orange", width=0.5, align="edge")

# settings (0,0):
ax1.set_xlabel("Gießtemperatur / °C")
ax1.set_ylim(0, 250)
ax2.set_ylim(0, 5)
ax1.set_ylabel("Rp0,2 und Rm / N/mm²")
ax2.set_ylabel("Bruchdehnung / %")

plt.show()
```

It's planned as a (1,2)-grid but there's nothing in (0,1) yet.

What do i do to get xticks and Labeling for 585,590,595,605 and still be able to have three bars next to each other?

Thanks for the help and cheers,

Alex

Comment: As [commented on your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53434496/x-axis-tick-spacing#comment93748698_53434496), you would plot against the index instead of the data and then set the labels accordingly.

Comment: Hey there, i really need help how to get the index as my x-values. I used "xpos=pd.DataFrame(index=["585","590","595","605"],dtype=int)" to get a list but i get the ValueError: "shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape" if i want to use it to plot the bars. Is it possible for you to give me the piece of code to define "xpos" so i can use it to plot?

Comment: Use `np.arange(4)` fot the x-data and then set the labels to the true values.